# Detecting tab bar item selection

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

For simplicity I am going to reffer my viewControllers as VC1,VC2...

I have a `TabBarController` as my root `viewController`. It contains 3 tabs, each containing a `UITableViewController`. So I have VC1 at index 0 of `TabBarController`, VC2 at index 1 and VC3 and index 2. Now I want to detect whenever user taps on index 0 of `TabBarController` to go to VC1. I have tried it using `UITabBarDelegate` as follows.

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

    if self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 0 {
        // do something
    }
}
```

It does work when I goto VC2 from VC1 and come back to VC1 from VC2. But it does not work if I go to VC3 from VC1 and then come back to VC1. Can someone explain why ?

What I actually want to achieve is that user go to VC3 from VC2 or VC1. Now user taps on a tableViewCell which takes to VC4. Now whenever user comeback to VC1 I want to call a webService.

Comment: how do you set them?

Comment: you could simply try `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {         
        if self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 0  {
           print("vc1") } }` apply same code to your `VC2` and `VC3` with `selectedIndex` 1,2....?

Answer (score 3):

instead of testing tabcontroller selectedIndex, caluculate selected index yourself:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

    let selectedIndex = tabBarController.viewControllers.index(of: viewcontroller)!
    if selectedIndex == 0 {
        // do something
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this `delegate` method to UITabBarController

```
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

}
```

This method will gets called whenever you select any item on TabBar

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly you may try below; First try to check view controller like below

```
if ([instance1 isKindOfClass:[CustomUIViewController class]]) {
    // then call web service.
}
```

Hope this will resolved the issue.